# How to update mongodb document with complex field from another document?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following 2 mongodb documents:

```
{
  "id" : "me@something.com",
  "Sales Data" : {
    "Company" : "Some Company",
    "PhoneNumber" : "301-555-1212",
    "City" : "Baltimore",
    "State" : "MD",
    "Orders" : {
      "0" : {
        "ProductId" : "ABC",
        "Quantity" : "3"
      },
      "1" : {
        "ProductId" : "DEF",
        "Quantity" : "2"
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "id": "you@company.com",
  "Sales Data" : {
    "Company" : "Your Company",
    "PhoneNumber" : "",
    "City" : "",
    "State" : ""
  }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to write a mongodb `update` statement that will update the "Sales Data" field of the second document with the "Sales Data" field data from the first document. Even if I have to manually construct the update statement that is fine.  I just can't figure out the syntax.  I tried something like this but it doesn't work

`db.getCollection('MyCollection').update({id: "you@company.com"}, {$set: {"Sales Data": "???"});`

Comment: How about `var coll = db.getCollection('MyCollection'), salesData = coll.findOne({id: "me@company.com"})["Sales Data"]; coll.updateOne({id: "you@company.com"}, {$set: {"Sales Data": salesData});`?

Comment: Hmmm.  What if the two documents are in different mongodb instances completely?

Comment: You'd have to write a script to query the first instance, get the `salesData` as above, open connection to the other instance and then update the document.

Comment: Can you point me to any sort of instructions or tutorials for how to write that kind of script?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @chridam I was able to figure it out.  I just used the mongo shell and wrote a small script that did the trick.  It looked like this:

```
db1 = connect("instance1Url/myDb1","myUserName","myPassword");
coll1 = db1.getCollection("myCollection");
salesData = coll1.findOne({id:"me@something.com"})["Sales Data"];

db2 = connect("instance2Url/myDB2", "myUserName", "myPassword");
coll2 = db2.getCollection("myCollection");
coll2.updateOne({id:"you@company.com"}, {$set: {"Sales Data": salesData}});
```